# Singleton Memory Management (Multiple Classes)

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, singleton

I have a singleton called `Singleton` that manages certain variables needed across the application for me.

I am using a View Controller `HomeViewController` which initializes the singleton on `viewDidLoad` and then sends a message to a server and receives information. It then takes that information and parses it with a separate class `XMLParser`.

When the `XMLParser` is done parsing it sends a notification to `HomeViewController` that it is done, and then `HomeViewController` dumps the data into `NSLog`.

In my `XMLParser` class, I call `[singleton setXX:XX]` and then `NSLog(@"%@", [[singleton XX]description]);` which dumps the data perfectly. If I go back to `HomeViewController` (after the notification posts) and try to log that same data it returns `Null`.

I tried not initializing the singleton in `viewDidLoad` and moving the initialization until after I receive the notification saying that the parse is complete, but I still get `Null`. Any ideas? I'm sure it has something to do with memory management (ARC, btw), but I am not sure exactly where.

Edit: Here is my `Singleton` code.

```
//.h
//...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *linkedList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *sessionData;

+ (id)sharedSingleton;

//.m
static MySingleton *sharedSingleton = nil;

@implementation MySingleton

@synthesize linkedList, sessionData;
+ (id)sharedSingleton {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedSingleton == nil)
            sharedSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedSingleton;
}
```

Edit2: Here are my singleton accessor methods, etc.

```
//XMLParser
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        if (!singleton) singleton = [[MySingleton alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
//...cut because no singleton access
//Closing Element
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SessionData"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Completed with SessionData. ID:11116");
        [singleton setSessionData:sessionData];
        NSLog(@"SessionData Description: \n%@", [sessionData description]);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushToScreen" object:nil];
        return;
    }
}

//HomeViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    singleton = [MySingleton sharedSingleton];
}
//...cut for useless code
//Then when notification received, it calls this selector
- (void)connect
{
    //singleton = [MySingleton sharedSingleton];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[singleton linkedList]description]);
}
```

Comment: We need to see how you're accessing the singleton in both XMLParser and HomeViewController.  Don't type an approximation of your code.  Just copy and paste the actual code.

Comment: What do your @property declarations look like? Are they retaining the values passed to your setter methods?

Comment: Updated. Singleton is at the top, all the rest below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `[[MySingleton alloc] init]` from another class completely negates the purpose of a singleton. You should only be accessing the singleton via the `sharedSingleton` class reference. All of the logic pertaining to whether an instance has been established is encapsulated inside the singleton. This way you're sure that you're always receiving the same instance back.

In your case, you've created a new instance of `Singleton`, completely bypassing the shared instance that is used by `HomeViewController`, in `XMLParser`'s `-init` method.

Your `-parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` method is setting session data on a brand new instance of `Singleton` and not the shared instance that is accessed via the `sharedInstance` class method. Once `HomeViewController` receives the notification, it checks the shared instance and the properties are nil because the wrong instance was being populated. Remove the `-init` method and `singleton` ivar from `XMLParser` and only use `[Singleton sharedInstance]` instead.

Comment: Oh jeeze... I'm smacking myself on the head right now! I can't believe I missed this when going through it again. I feel like such an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

What's the code for your Singleton? Mine always looks something like this:

```
BookDescriptorDataModel* BookDescriptorDataModel_instance;
+(BookDescriptorDataModel*)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!BookDescriptorDataModel_instance)
        {
            BookDescriptorDataModel_instance = [[BookDescriptorDataModel alloc] init];
            [BookDescriptorDataModel_instance load];
        }
    }
    return BookDescriptorDataModel_instance;
}
```

Also, how are you storing your data?  Mine looks something like this:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDictionary* bookDescriptor;
```